# Add http and https domains with bash scripting

Tags: linux, scripting, dns

I have a list of domains and I would like to add the prefix http and https each.
in order to pass through a proxy to add a target to burp suite,
For this I am using curl, but just add " http":

```
xargs -n1 -P 10 curl -o /dev/null --silent -x 127.0.0.1:8080 --head --write-out '%{url_effective}: %{http_code}\n' < list_domains
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk  '{print "http://" $1}' list_domains | xargs....
```